# Is it better to have a CASE expression or a JOIN with a dimensional table?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, performance, redshift

I have a fact table which has a timestamp and I want to express the day of the week. I could do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date_part(timestamp,'week') = 0 then 'Monday'
WHEN date_part(timestamp,'week') = 1 then 'Tuestday'...
FROM fact_table
```

Or I could create a dimensional table like the following:

```
day_number day_name
0          Monday
1          Tuesday
```

and then make a JOIN with the fact table:

```
SELECT day_name
FROM fact_table
LEFT JOIN dm_days
on day_number = date_part(timestamp, 'week')
```

Which one is better?

What if instead of a date is some indicator (for instance where the traffic comes from: newsletter, SEO, affiliates...) that does not require any function (like date_part) to be obtained? For example, would this be better:

```
SELECT CASE id_channel WHEN 0 then 'SEO'
WHEN 1 then 'Newsletter'...
FROM fact_table
```

Than this?
    SELECT channel_name
    FROM fact_table
    LEFT JOIN dm_channels
    on channel_id = id_channel

Comment: Specify **ONE** DBMS,  please. Including version.

Comment: Does the answer really changes depending on the database? I thought it was something more general

Comment: In variant 1 use `CASE date_part(timestamp,'week') WHEN 0 then 'Monday' WHEN 1 then 'Tuestday' ...`. But anycase I prefer 2nd variant - if you need to change something, in 1st var. you need DDL whereas in 2nd - DML only.

Comment: *Does the answer really changes depending on the database?* In this particular case the best way is to use datetime formatting function for to obtain weekday name...

Comment: In Postgres I would use neither, instead I would use: `to_char(the_column, 'Day')`

Comment: it really depends on which spelling of `Tuesday` you prefer :)

Answer (score 1):

For this problem I would use the date formatting functions (after setting `lc_time` to the appropriate locale)

```
SELECT to_char(timestamp, 'Day') 
FROM fact_table
```

In general the table form is, to me, cleaner (when there is no suitable function)

Perhaps with an in-line table if there is a good reason to not have a permanent table.

```
SELECT day_name
FROM fact_table
LEFT JOIN (VALUES (1,'Monday'),(2,'Tuesday'),(3,'Wednesday')) AS days(day_number ,day_name ) 
on day_number = date_part('dow',timestamp)::int
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither, for MySQL:

```
SELECT ts, DATE_FORMAT(ts, '%W') AS W,
           DATE_FORMAT(ts, '%a') AS a   FROM ...
+---------------------+--------+------+
| ts                  | W      | a    |
+---------------------+--------+------+
| 2020-01-26 10:53:05 | Sunday | Sun  |
+---------------------+--------+------+
```

That is, just use an expression.